# WCH CH355 Quad serial card not assinged ttyS* after reboot / upgrade

Tags: drivers, serial-port

I have a quad port serial port based on the WCH CH355 chip.
It had been working fine for over a year. Then I rebooted....
It used to be ttyS4 - ttyS7

I think that this is a kernal version problem but I could be wrong.
I don't recall that there was anything special I did to get this to work. That does not mean that I didn't. Just don't remember...

Thanks

lspci lists the card

```
37:04.0 Serial controller: WCH.CN CH355 PCI Quad Serial Port Controller (rev 10)
```

dsmg | grep 37:

```
[    0.312115] pci 0000:37:04.0: [4348:7173] type 00 class 0x070002
[    0.312134] pci 0000:37:04.0: reg 0x10: [io  0xd040-0xd047]
[    0.312143] pci 0000:37:04.0: reg 0x14: [io  0xd048-0xd04f]
[    0.312152] pci 0000:37:04.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xd050-0xd057]
[    0.312162] pci 0000:37:04.0: reg 0x1c: [io  0xd058-0xd05f]
[    0.312171] pci 0000:37:04.0: reg 0x20: [io  0xd000-0xd03f]
[    0.312259] pci 0000:37:09.0: [11c1:5811] type 00 class 0x0c0010
[    0.312278] pci 0000:37:09.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf9000000-0xf9000fff]
[    0.312347] pci 0000:37:09.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.312349] pci 0000:37:09.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot
[    0.358239] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 0 [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    0.358240] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 1 [mem 0xf9000000-0xf90fffff]
[    0.358241] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 4 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    0.358243] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 5 [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff window]
[    0.358244] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 6 [mem 0xf8000000-0xf9ffffff window]
[    0.358245] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 7 [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed003ff window]
[    0.358246] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 8 [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed44fff window]
[    0.358247] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 9 [io  0x0000-0x03af window]
[    0.358249] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 10 [io  0x03b0-0x03df window]
[    0.358250] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 11 [io  0x03e0-0x0cf7 window]
[    0.358251] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 12 [io  0x0d00-0x0fff window]
[    0.358252] pci_bus 0000:37: resource 13 [io  0x1000-0xdfff window]
[    7.920092] firewire_ohci 0000:37:09.0: added OHCI v1.0 device as card 0, 8 IR + 8 IT contexts, quirks 0x0
[    8.476198] firewire_core 0000:37:09.0: created device fw0: GUID 0060b000007a97ac, S400
```

So it sees it
But setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123456789]

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS4, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS5, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS6, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS7, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS8, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS9, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
```

I think that this may be an update issue. I don't recall what I was running before but now
uname -a

```
Linux bobfish 4.15.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 21:54:34 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As Requested:
lspci -knn | grep -i serial -A3

```
37:04.0 Serial controller [0700]: WCH.CN CH355 PCI Quad Serial Port Controller [4348:7173] (rev 10)
            Subsystem: WCH.CN CH355 PCI Quad Serial Port Controller [4348:3473]    
    37:09.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller [11c1:5811] (rev 70)
            Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller [103c:130b]
            Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
```

Comment: Add the output of  `lspci -knn | grep -i serial  -A3`

Comment: Anybody???This used to work. I can not get setserial to configure this correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many many many hours of rebooting and Google searches I finally found an answer.

I bought a different serial card for $17.

The WCH 355 card is in the documentation that I found as being supported.
The card would be found about every 5th reboot. I can only guess that there is some register that comes up random and maybe every 5th reboot it was recognized. 
( It was always recognised under windows )

So for $17 it would have been better to just buy a new card immediately.

I am posting this for someone else to find when they buy this card.